Does the derivative of the antiderivative of a BV function $f$ agree with $f$ at all but countably many points of differentiability?
Let $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb R$ be a function of bounded variation, and write
$$F(x) := \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$$
for the antiderivative. Is it true that at all but countably points of differentiability of $F$, we have $F’ = f$?
More precisely, let $D$ denote the set of differentiability of $F$. Does there exist some countable set $B \subset D$ of bad points such that $F’ = f$ on $D \setminus B$?

The answer is yes.
Indeed, since $f$ is of bounded variation, by changing values of $f$ at at most countably many points, without loss of generality assume that $f$ is right continuous. So, $f=g+h$, where $g$ is a continuous function and $h(x)=\sum_{y\in D\cap(a,x]}a_y$ for some at most countable subset $D$ of $(a,b)$, some real family $(a_y)_{y\in D}$ such that $\sum_{y\in D}|a_y|<\infty$, and all $x\in(a,b)$.
So, $D^c:=(a,b)\setminus D$ is the set of all points of continuity of $h$ and, equivalently, of $f$. Moreover, $D^c$ is the set of all points of differentiability of $F$, and $F'=f$ on $D^c$.

Ah… you subtract off the points of discontinuity, which are only countably many. However, can we be sure that $F$ is not differentiable on $D$?

Oh, the left and right derivatives are different, nice.

@NateRiver : Yes, because $\sum_{y\in D}|a_y|<\infty$.

And so these jumps cannot interfere with the left and right derivatives - we have that their difference is $J$ exactly, where $J$ is the size of the jump. Very nice.

Also we may say: a BV function is a difference of two increasing functions whose set of discontinuity are disjoint; an increasing function has at most countably many discontinuity points; the integral function $F$ of a monotone function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ iff $f$ is continuous at $x$, in which case $F'(x)=f(x)$.

This charming theorem proves useful once again...

Ora also: every BV function on (a,b) is sum of an increasing function and a decreasing continuous function, so it is sufficient to consider the case of increasing $f$
